# VBA pricelist with images: TopLeftCell gives wrong Adress

Tags: excel, vba

**Hi all**
for my customer I am creating lingerie shop. I've got price list in excel file and trying to get images like below:

[image: My Excell file]

I am using solution found [Excel VBA: How Check the Name of Picture Inside the Cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32092387/excel-vba-how-check-the-name-of-picture-inside-the-cell) 
I slightly modified code:

```
Sub CheckImageName()
Dim pic                   As Excel.Picture


For Each pic In ActiveSheet.Pictures


    'pic.Top = pic.Top + 20
    'pic.Left = pic.Left + 20
   pic.TopLeftCell.Value = pic.Name






Next pic
end sub
```

Simultaneously I've opened XLSX as ZIP end get all images from sheet.

**The problem is, that image name in cell is not corresponding with image content. In selected case image279.jpg is:**

[image: My Excell file]

What I am doying wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Tomasz, I see from your first screenshot that `image279.jpg` is actually stored in the cell's value (`B281`), instead of the picture's name itself.

[image]

Here's where you should store your picture's name in order to make your code work (select the picture > name box in the top-left corner):

[image]

Comment: Heh i see now true problem: 
image 281 is okat and it should be in row 279  (https://ibb.co/DKcRDCX)
, but when i open XLSX as a zip file this image into 179